# How to override method in wrapped class?

Tags: java, methods, overriding, extends, implements

I have the following classes defined...

```
class Class2 implements ICommon {
    ....
    ICommon  wrappedClass;
    //delegate interface methods to wrapped class
}

class Class1 implements ICommon {
    //interface methods
    //specific methods
    public void method1() {
        ......
    }
}
```

I need to make `Class1` overwrite the `method1()` of `Class2`, however I still want to implement the `ICommon` interface. Is there any way that this could be achieved?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense.  What do you mean by "override method1 of Class1 in Class2"?  I presume method1 is not part of ICommon, based on the comments in your examples, but that means that method1 is not present in Class2, so overriding it there makes no logical sense.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot override without extending. Class2 has to extend Class1, then you will be able to override.

```
class Class2 extends Class1 // no need for implements anymore, because class1 already implements
{

    @Override
    public void method1()
    {

    }
}
```

Know that this design means that every Class2 is a Class1, just like every Ant is a Bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Class1 extends Class2{
     ...method1((){
          ......
       }
 }
```

Class2 is already implementing IComm interface so Class1 is indirectly implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, just:

```
class Class2 extends Class1 implements ICommon {
 ....
  ICommon  wrappedClass;
  //delegate interface methods to wrapped class

  @Override 
  public void method1 () {...}
}
```

That should work fine, no?  You don't even need the `implements ICommon` since `Class` does that already, I just put it there to make it clear that it did.

To be clear, this requires no changes to `ICommon` whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You could make Class1 an Interface...

```
class Class2 implements ICommon, Class1 {
    ICommon  wrappedClass;
}

interface Class1 extends ICommon {
    public void method1();
}
```

Or make Class1 extend Class2 (by doing this, Class1 still implements ICommon because Class2 implements ICommon)...

```
class Class2 implements ICommon {
    ICommon  wrappedClass;
}

class Class1 extends Class2 {
    public void method1() {
    }
}
```